# MSChart - Stacked Column having two values per series

Tags: c#, charts, mschart, stacked

is it possible to display two values in one series in a multiple series column chart

ex. i have products per category, each product has got two values, the selling & buying value

so if we plot categories against x axis and products as multiple series per category having values of buying and selling

Category=>Product
       (one to many)

a product can belong to one or more categories

can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

One series can have multiple y values eg y1,y2 etc

Comment: yes having multiple values per series is possible, but how do i plot the same on the chart, if i use stacked column chart then it stacks series on one another.

in my case i want to have multiple series per X axis value displaying two different values on each individual series

Any idea if this is possible or not?

Comment: NO you cannot use column chart to display multiple values. Use Bubble chart or other chart where multiple y Values make any sense.    Check here for series which can have multiple Y Values http://support.dundas.com/Dashboard25.Chart_ChartTypes.ashx

Comment: thanks for the link @Quantbuff, but had already referred to the various chart types as stated in the link, may be the requirement is not possible through ms-chart control, would think of a workaround now in such a case!